# Data from client not getting reflected in server using node.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to emulate a chat using the example provided in http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

I have all the dependencies specified in the package.json file and also installed using npm the respective dependencies.

My js file has the following code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req,res){
   res.sendFile(__dirname+ '/chat.html');

});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
});

http.listen(8083, function(){
console.log("listening on port 8083");
});
```

My html code is like:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io();
$('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('chat message', 'Test');
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
});
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

i am able to connect to the server. however when i type text in the text box, this is not getting reflected in the server. where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong with the form submit handler. They are trying to catch the form submit event and then override it using return false, but the form is still submitting anyway, causing the entire page to reload.

Instead, I'd just suggest getting rid of the form and just using a button to trigger the send.  Bind an onclick handler to the element and then fire the socket.emit method:

```
<!-- include jQuery for convenience -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();

      // add in document ready to only bind to the element once the page is done loading
      $(document).ready(function() {

        // use the click handler instead of form submit handler
        $('#button').click(function(){
          console.log('sending...')
         socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
         $('#m').val('');
         return false;
       });
     });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
     <form action="">

      <!-- give the button element an id to bind to -->
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button id="button">Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
```

I also added in jQuery, since it looked like that's what their demo was using, but they didn't include it in the HTML demo.

With this, the message will make it to the server, but you will still need to do work to get it to publish back to the client.  The rest of the tutorial on the Socket.IO site may address that issue.

Comment: it works! so is it advisable always to have a button click handler instead of form submit?